Spark Submit Job Failure- Container released on a *lost* node.))
I am running a spark submit command, where I need to store my data grouped by companyId to s3 as text files, where partitionedBy is by textId. I do have 3 millions records.
Error:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Authorized committer (attemptNumber=0, stage=21, partition=462) failed; but task commit success, data duplication may happen. reason=ExecutorLostFailure(31,false,Some(Container marked as failed: container_ on host:  Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a lost node.))
I am able to run the job successfully with less data. I am getting this error when handling huge amount of data.
Spark configs:
    '--conf', 'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true',
    '--conf', 'spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=10',
    '--conf', 'spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=200',
    '--conf', 'maximizeResourceAllocation=true',
    '--conf', 'spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10',
     '--conf', 'spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1',
    '--driver-memory', '16G',
    '--executor-memory', '8G',
    '--executor-cores', '4'

This spark job will be running on emr cluster. spark dependency version is 3.5
Code snippet:
transformedDataWithCompanyId is of type Dataset
Dataset rowDataset = transformedDataWithTextId.toDF(TEXT_ID_END_DATE, DATA).repartition(jobParams.getPartitions());
            rowDataset.write().mode(OVERWRITE).partitionBy(TEXT_ID_END_DATE).text(jobParams.getWeeklyOutputS3Location());
            

We tried increasing partitions, removed partitions count, increased spark conf values
